# Problems with remote accessing a new instance in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to setup a new dev environment. I have installed a Windows Server 2022 with SQL Server 2019 on it.

My idea is to setup a new instance for every project I make.

But I'm having trouble installing new instances and connecting to them remotely.

What I do:

Start setup -> create new instance -> put in instance name let the wizard finish.

To access remotely, I went to configuration manager and enabled tcp/ip and named pipes.

I restarted all services.

In the firewall port 1433 tcp and port 1434 udp are enabled.

My default instance `sqlexpress` is accessible for remote connection, So I can definitely say it is not a firewall issue.

I currently tried 3 times where the first time I was able to connect locally but not remotely, other 2 time failed to even connect locally even after restarting my virtual machine. Locally and remotely I'm getting error 26. googling around doesn't find the right answer.

[image: services]

[image: configuration manager]

[image: firewall]

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and or give me the steps to install a new instance and allow it to connect remotely?

Comment: What TCP/IP port(s) is the NETWORKMONITOR instance listening on? Only one instance can be listening on tcp/1433 on any particular address, so if the SQLEXPRESS instance was already listening there then the new instance must be listening on a different port.

Comment: Each instance is on a separate port. You need to open the firewall to `sqlservr.exe` on any port.

Comment: ow, that's a good point, I didn't knew that. I was thinking about that too but rather weird that I was able to connect locally. I have connected to server with multiple instances withouth the need to enter a port in the connectionstring or via ssms

Comment: How do I set the port on the instance if ssms cannot connect to it locally?

Comment: You don't use SSMS for this. You use the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Up Named SQL Server Instance Network Connection](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270745/setting-up-named-sql-server-instance-network-connection)

Comment: You can connect locally because it doesn't use TCP it uses shared memory, and in any case the firewall doesn't normally block `localhost`

Comment: Yes, I have managed to fix it, I changed the listening port in the configuration manager and then open up a firewall rule, and restarted my services. for some reason I wasn't able to connect but after a total vm restart I was able to connect. So I can only assume I forgot to restart a specific server accept I don't know which one, as I restarted all of the sql servicers except the agent services because they are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, My problem was both instances were listening to the same port.
When replacing the ports by changing to a seperate port for each instance, everything works.